# Centroids of clusters in 3D sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix

I have a 3D sparse matrix, with lots of zeroes and a few ones. Some of the non-zero values are grouped in clusters, and I need to find the center of mass of each cluster. For each cluster, some elements are 1-connected and some not.

How would you approach the problem in Matlab?

See below for an overview of the data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and single-linkage hierarchical clustering.

But I don't think there is a good Matlab implementation of DBSCAN.

Also, the center of mass of such data may be meaningless - the clusters may be concave; so the center may be *outside* of the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on DBSCAN, and no worries for the concave case - even results that are outside the cluster are acceptable. Cheers!